# Why is the flags argument in open/send/sendto/sendmsg functions a signed integer and not an unsigned integer?

Tags: c, linux, posix

As you see in the manpages:

```
   ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);

   ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                  const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);

   ssize_t sendmsg(int sockfd, const struct msghdr *msg, int flags);
```

Comment: The sockets (BSD) APIs predates both POSIX and C89. Modifying socket APIs would existing break code and there's no pressing need to make them 'unsigned'. POSIX says file descriptor can't be negative. So you can make the same argument for the first argument of `send*()` as well. I suspect the reason is "historical" (probably just an arbitrary choice).

Answer (score 1):

As there is no reason to add/subtract flags from flags, nor a reason to convert it to any other type and the only operations done on flags is the bitwise operators to set flag bits or to test if one or more bits have been set, there is no reason for it to be defined as either signed or unsigned. Both will be fine.

Comment: `int` is always signed, so it *is* defined as signed!

Comment: @undeifned-behavior, that is what i say i said 'signed', not `signed`.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Yes, but what the answer says is that there is no specific need for it to be signed. Of course it has to be one or the other.